# Offline mode on iOS through Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, video

I have an application which has video content (something like youtube)
I want to make an offline mode in my app (no internet connection mode)

1. The end user will download video sources
2. Video sources will be saved on the device
3. When the app will be opened on offline mode the end user will get the offline video content

I will be happy to hear what is the best way to implement this kind of logic, I heard about Core Data is there some source code or an example you know about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is very generic. You should provide some details about your goal.

Core Data in this case could be a lot of work. Especially for its learning curve.

A simple solution could be to save videos on file systems and use plist files (or whatever you want) to contains the path (meta-informations) where videos are stored in.

Anyway, if you want to adopt Core Data, this will contain only meta-informations about videos. And not videos. As before they will be saved on disk. Maybe external storage functionality could be the right way to follow.

Comment: Hi flexaddicted, thanks for your answer.. after a small research I understood that the best for me will be core data + file system.
what you think?

Comment: @ElizaS If you want flexibility, yes. It's the right way to follow. Out there you can find a lot of resources. Good work!!

Comment: Thank you very much, if you have some github examples which specifically are focused on video I will be happy to get the urls.
10x again!

Comment: @ElizaS Yo're welcome. Out there there are samples for images. You can start with them to have an understanding on how it works.